# PHP-Ews | ErrorInvalidIdMalformed: Id is malformed

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, php-ews

I am currently working on a script fetching subjects and attachements from an email received with Exchange.

For this purpose, I have found **php-ews** and used [one of the provided examples](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/blob/master/examples/message/get-attachments.php) to retrieve the attachments.
The script throws `ErrorInvalidIdMalformed: Id is malformed` when I try running it.

I would have guessed I made a mistake getting the MessageID from Outlook, but it seems that there is only one field labeled "MessageID". It looks like this:
*3cbab9c9ad50410592b55f7ade96a57a@[domain].fr*

Is there anything I have missed ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

> ErrorInvalidIdMalformed

means that there is structural issues with the `MessageID` string that is being passed in.
However, there doesn't seem to be any problems with the `MessageID` you posted.

You could try serializing the `GetItemRequest` instance via an *[XmlSerializer](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer)* and then examine the actual xml for issues. (maybe post the actual xml to your question).

I would guess that there is a character missing from your xml or else it contains something it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your confusing the EWSId with the MessageId, the EWSid is the identifier that can be used to access an Item directly see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605828%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx for a full discussion.

The messageId 3cbab9c9ad50410592b55f7ade96a57a@[domain].fr in your instance is the Internet MessageID which is assigned generally by the first MTA to  process the Message. You can search for a Message with this ID using EWS and the FindItem operation eg [Exchange Web Service find EmailMessage by "Message-ID" header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435207/exchange-web-service-find-emailmessage-by-message-id-header) but you can't use that ID to bind to the item directly. (if you do just want an ewsId you can bind to directly use the EWSEditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ to get a bindable example)